# Javascript object encoding/decoding when passing a message to an API

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, azureservicebus

I am passing a message to a third party message queue which relays the message to my queue listener (all in node.js server side). The message has a predefined format which allows me to define "custom properties". This works fine when I provide basic types (string, number, etc) but when I try and pass an object in the custom properties, it fails.

Sending this message:

```
var info = {foo: 100};
var message = {
    body: 'some string',
    customProperties: {
        type: 1,
        name: 'test',
        info: info
    }
};
```

Returns this message:

```
{
    body: 'some string',
    customProperties: {
        type: 1,
        name: 'test',
        info: '[object Object]' 
    }
};
```

And sending this message:

```
var info = {foo: 100};
var message = {
    body: 'some string',
    customProperties: {
        type: 1,
        name: 'test',
        info: JSON.stringify(info)
    }
};
```

Returns this message:

```
{
    body: 'some string',
    customProperties: {
        type: 1,
        name: 'test',
        info: '\\"{\\"foo\\":100}\\"' 
    }
};
```

Which then fails when I try to decode it with `JSON.parse(customProperties.info)`. I think what is happening is that it is calling `.toString` on each custom property? Any ideas how I can encode/decode a simple object when passing this message?

Comment: Can you show the bit of code you use to pass these messages? What kind of 3rd party message queue (and library?) are you using?

Comment: Azure service bus. It's basically bus.send(message); and bus.receive(function(err, message) { }); That all works fine so long as I don't include an object in the message.

Comment: Something performs extra escaping, which breaks JSON

Comment: @zerkms yes, the question is how to work around that since I don't control the API.

Comment: What if you JSON encode `customProperties` before sending, so that `message` has two simple string properties, i.e. `body` and `customProperties`

Comment: I'm guessing that this is a /feature/ of Azure service bus, which only allows primitive types as values of custom properties.

Comment: @AndrewEisenberg `JSON.stringify(info)` is of a primitive type, it's a string.

Comment: @Val `customProperties` must be an object. This is a predefined message format. I think the API is probably iterating all the properties of `customProperties` and calling `.toString()` before sending to the server.

Comment: @Joel what if you add a `foo: '"'` property (as another entry in `customProperties`)? What would it return?

Comment: @zerkms foo: '"' returns foo: '\\"\\"\\"'

Comment: @Joel you are right. See [this link (setRequestHeaders)](http://dl.windowsazure.com/nodedocs/servicebusservice.js.html), it's because `customProperties` is sent via a header, and thus, as a string, but look at how each properties is stringified.

Comment: @zerkms Yes. Exactly. String is a primitive type, but Object is not. Likely, the protocol calls toString() on all non-primitives.

Comment: @Val nice find. So any ideas how to encode/decode an object into a string so it doesn't mess it up?

Comment: Yes, see my answer below!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution around this would be to encode `info` in another format that wouldn't be modified during the `setRequestHeaders()` call in [Azure's ServiceBus](http://dl.windowsazure.com/nodedocs/servicebusservice.js.html). You can JSON encode your string as you did in the second solution, but then you can Base64 encode the result like this:

```
var info = {foo: 100};
var message = {
    body: 'some string',
    customProperties: {
        type: 1,
        name: 'test',
        info: btoa(JSON.stringify(info))
    }
};
```

This will yield `customProperties` like this:

```
{type: 1, name: "test", info: "eyJmb28iOjEwMH0="}
```

And then for decoding, you simply do

```
var info = JSON.parse(atob(message.customProperties.info));
```

which yields

```
{foo: 100}
```

Comment: It's not clear why a string after `btoa` will be treated as not a string.

Comment: It will be treated as a string but calling `toString` on it won't change its content to it can be decoded back safely.

Comment: "It will be treated as a string but calling toString on it won't change its content " --- why would `.toString()` change a content of any string at first place? `'"'.toString()` is still a `'"'` string.

Comment: Well, your solution does not address any problem you've pointed to in the source code. It is still a string so it will be processed as any other string has.

Comment: "Any ideas how I can encode/decode a simple object when passing this message?" Sounds perfectly valid to me

Comment: This solution worked by removing any double quotations from the source string. There is something in the Azure source code that breaks when a " is included in a string being passed. They do this to the string when preparing the message `value = '\"' + value.toString() + '\"'`

Comment: @Val before I mark as correct, does converting to Base64 guarantee that there won't be a double quote in the encoded string? My Base64 is a bit rusty....

Comment: @Joel I suspect they do that even before that line, so base64'ing it is an ugly hack not a valid solution I think.

Comment: The [Base64 alphabet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) doesn't contain any double quotes, indeed.

Comment: @zerkms the hack is in the Azure source code already, so we just unhack it ;-) But I agree with you, it would be nicer if Azure would detect JSON encoded strings and do nothing with them.

Comment: @Val actually even easier - one could just always apply JSON without any detection. Explicit is better than implicit.